# Multiple bitwise operators in one line

Tags: binary, operators, bit-manipulation

Ok, I'm trying to shove all these smaller numbers into one 32 bit number, all in one line. Since a is 101, b is 001, and d is 011, I thought an or with all those shifts would return to me 101001011, or 331. but cout returns 1.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    a = 5;
    b = 1;
    d = 3;
    c = 0;

    c = ( 0 || a << 8 || b << 5 || d << 2 );
    cout << c;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using logical "or"s. Your result is "true". Use single pipes "|"

```
c = ( 0 | a << 8 | b << 5 | d << 2 );
```